# How to search for specific letter in a word, then add that word with that letter to a list?

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

I have been given a task for some homework and need some help.

The task is as follows: *A user is asked to enter a sentence, one word at a time. When the letter **a** is entered(in a word) input is stopped. Whenever the letter **a** is in a word, add that word to a list, when sentence is finshed, print the list*

I have thought about it and have ruled out while loops( correct me if I'm wrong) and thought about using for loops/statements.

EDIT: here is the pseudocode:

-Create an Empty list

-initiate response=space ie."while response is not"

-append to list

-get word from user

-print list

If anyone could help me it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: an example would be better.

Comment: Would you like the psuedocode?

Comment: it's hard to understand.

Comment: I know, thats why I'm stuck. From what I can gather, whenever a word is entered with the letter "a" in that word, that word must be added to a list. When the program is finished, print the list with all the words including the letter "a"

Comment: Please write some code and show us if not we can't help

Comment: I don't have any code because I dont know how to start, If i was writing code it would be added to my question. I just need to know how to go about this. All I have been given is a question/ task to complete without anything else other than the pseudo code provided

Comment: Well you can start here https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/

Comment: All the code I have at the moment is what Joe. R has given, you can see that below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand you correctly, but if the word the user inputs contains the letter **a**, you want that word to be added to a list, this is how you can do that.

```
word = raw_input("Enter word: ")
lst = []
if "a" in word:
    lst.append(word)
    print lst
```

`raw_input` id in Python 2, you can use `input` in Python 3

Comment: BTW: if this answer helped, you can click to accept this as the right answer

Comment: Doing someones homework for them  is not going to help them learn.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes, I agree with you in principle, however, this is what the OP wrote in his comment: "I don't have any code because I dont know how to start, If i was writing code it would be added to my question. I just need to know how to go about this." so it seemed like he was trying to learn but he was really stuck. I think the answer pointed him in the right direction. That said, I may be wrong about this.

Comment: I'm not asking for people to do my homework for me, I just need somewhere to start, I need help because I am very confused

Comment: @RedFistFilms, read a book, look at a tutorial, there are numerous ways to learn and I am sure based on your question you are either doing an online course or this is school work so you have teachers or other means to get help.

Comment: I have been doing Python work for 2 year during school( although the first year didn't count due to a crappy teacher) We only just started learning about list and dictionaries last week. I missed all but one lesson due to being sick. I have sent numerous messages to my teacher and have no replies thus far, that is why I turned to StackOverflow